# Add a login form to my module

Tags: forms, users

I want to add the login form to a custom page I've created using a custom module, but I dont know how?

Shouldn't there be a form to use like get_drupal_form?

Using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I used:

```
$html = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login'))
return $html;
```

Answer (score 3):

Drupal comes with a login block you can put in any of your theme regions to have show up on that page.

Or you can use `drupal_get_form('user_login')` if you want it to show up in your content somewhere.

Comment: Using drupal_get_form('user_login') and it only returns "Array" ?

Comment: I had to do it like this: drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_login'))